# How to prevent bluetooth from sending concatenated data

Tags: multithreading, bluetooth, outputstream

In advance, I want to say sorry for my poor english.

I'm working on a project which uses cellphone's bluetooth to send two bytes of data to a MCU through HC-05 bluetooth module each time. Since the MCU has no buffer to store the received data, I have to send one byte twice with interval at least 10ms.

I use an oscilloscope to monitor the HC-05 module. In most of time, my phone sends two packets with one byte of data in each, but sometimes it sends two packet together and therefore the MCU cannot handle it.

below is how I define the sending method

```
public void sendData(){

        Byte byte_send = (byte) Integer.parseInt(tmp_addr);
        byte[] tmp = new byte[]{byte_send};
        Byte byte_2 = (byte) Integer.parseInt(tmp_data);
        byte[] temp = new byte[]{byte_2};
        try {

            mOutStream.write(tmp);
            mOutStream.flush();

            this.sleep(20);

            mOutStream.write(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why causes that to happen? Is it because "sleep(20);" didn't work or something else?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post screenshots of your code. Copy/paste the actual code into your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the flush only means write the data from outputstream to Bluetooth stack does not mean write the data to remote device? sorry I was not check the code yet.
However for synchronize purpose, can your remote device echo the received data back then your app can send the second byte to remote?